# Erro em desvio no assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

Preciso transformar o seguinte código de c para assembly do MIPS:

```
int i;
int vetor[8];
  for(i=0; i<8; i++) {

    if(i%2==0)
    vetor[i] = i * 2;

    else
    vetor[i] = vetor[i] + vetor[i-1];
}
```

Fazendo isso cheguei no seguinte código:

```
.data
    .space 32 #reserva o espaço necessário pro vetor

.text
    #t0 = endereço inicial da memória de dados
    #t1 = divisor e multiplicador
    #t2 = contador
    #t3 = limite do contador
    #t4 = resto da divisão
    #t5 = resultado da multiplicação de i por 2
    #t6 = recupera o elemento da anterior da meméria para fazer a soma no else 

    lui $t0, 0x1001

    ori $t1, $zero, 2
    ori $t2, $zero, 0
    ori $t3, $zero, 8

    loop:       #faz o loop até 8(t3)
    beq $t2, $t3, exit

    div $t2, $t1        #divide i por 2
    mfhi $t4        #faz a a comparação do resto com $zero
    bne $t4 $zero, else #e pula para else caso seja impar

    mult $t1, $t2
    mfhi $t5 
    sw $t5, 0($t0)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    #incrementa o contador
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    #incrementa o "ponteiro" para o vetor

    j loop

    else:

    lw $t6, 0($t0)
    add $t5, $t5, $t6   #reutiliza $t5 que está com o valor anterior e soma com a posição atual da memória 
    sw $t5, 0($t0)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    #incrementa o contador
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    #incrementa o "ponteiro" para o vetor
    j loop

    exit:
```

Porém o loop do mesmo só funciona para as duas primeiras iterações, após isso ele simplesmente ignora o jump dentro da label *else*. Mas se eu comentar (apagar) os linhas no *else*, e deixar apenas o contador do loop não comentado ele percorre o *for* até o final.

else:

```
#lw $t6, 0($t0)
    #add $t5, $t5, $t6  #reutiliza $t5 que está com o valor anterior e soma com a posição atual da memória 
    #sw $t5, 0($t0)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    #incrementa o contador
    #addi $t0, $t0, 4   #incrementa o "ponteiro" para o vetor
    j loop
```

Mas não compreendi por que isso não estou alterando as variáveis relativas ao loop em nenhum lugar($t2 e $t3), a não ser no incrementador. Alguém consegue identificar onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Na arquitetura MIPS pipeline, as instruções de desvio alteram o PC em um momento
  em que a instrução seguinte já foi buscada e está prestes a ser
  executada (passo 3 do Ciclo de Máquina);

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Portanto, mesmo que haja um desvio (jump ou branch), a instrução a
  seguir será executada!
- SOLUÇÃO: sempre usar uma instrução nop (no operation) após instruções
  de desvio.